# Find the probability that there are only or exactly 4 consecutive heads in 7 tosses.

Tags: probability

In my previous edit, I asked whether the case, e.g. $HHHHTHH$ (4 consecutive heads and 2 consecutive heads) is possible regarding the question, "Find the probability that there are **only** 4 consecutive heads in 7 tosses."

Now, I would like to ask more about whether the case as stated above can be applied to the following one, "Find the probability that there are **exactly** consecutive heads in 7 tosses."

In my opinion, this case should not be possible since the word **'only'** or even **'exactly'** has restricted the case to have just 4 consecutive heads. Am I right?

Comment: You'd better ask the question's author what he meant.

Comment: It's likely the author meant "there exist 4 consecutive heads but not 5 consecutive heads", but ask them.

Comment: @obscurans So, the case including 2 consecutive heads and 4 consecutive heads is not allowed?

Comment: In this interpretation, nothing about lesser number of consecutive heads. 4+2 is fine. "Only" just means not 5+.

Comment: @obscurans Can you explain more about the reason that less than or equal to 4 consecutive heads is allowed in this interpretation? Thanks.

Comment: The reason is otherwise, you'd be asking for precisely: 4 heads in a row, and then either "no further consecutive heads" or even "no other consecutive tosses" (therefore strictly alternating heads/tails). This seems to be way too restrictive and isn't particularly interesting, so it is more "natural" (to me) to allow <=4 consecutive heads anywhere. That said, the question being ambiguous is the fault of the author.

Comment: The way you proceeded here doesn't work well with how the site works. You asked this question with "only". Then (apparently in response to the comments) you asked it with "exactly" as a separate question, without linking to this question, thus causing an unnecessary duplication of efforts. Now, after I closed that question as a duplicate of this one, you deleted it and edited this one without visibly marking the edit as such, thus invalidating several of the previously valid comments.

Comment: A more efficient approach would have been either to immediately edit this question, adding the variation with "exactly" and marking the edit as such, or, if you feel that that question is substantially different from the original one, you should have linked the new question to the old one, as they are obviously related and the new one might have profited from thoughts people had already contributed to the old one.

Comment: @joriki So, what should I do then? Can you give me some advice? Thanks.

Comment: @DiamondMaths: I did, it just took me a few seconds to post it after the first comment :-) Now that things stand as they do, I would suggest to edit the present question to make clear that you had originally asked about "only" but in light of the comments would like to know about both "only" and "exactly".

Comment: @joriki Should I change back to the original one then?

Comment: @DiamondMaths: I've edited my comment above in the meantime; sorry for the overlap

Comment: @joriki I have tried my best to edit it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108074/discussion-between-diamond-maths-and-joriki).

Comment: I doubt the question is related to probabilities or math.

Answer (score 1):

Both formulations are not entirely clear. It’s possible to arrive at a most plausible interpretation, but only by eliminating other possible interpretations as less plausible.

The problem is that it’s not clear which other possibilities “only” or “exactly” is meant to exclude. This could be further tosses in the same run, further runs with as many consecutive tosses, or even, as you seem to have interpreted it, further consecutive tosses, even in shorter runs.

A clue to the most plausible interpretation lies in looking closely at how the phrase “$4$ consecutive tosses” is conventionally used. If we take it literally, we’d have to construe “consecutive” as a property of heads. Possible candidates for this property might be that a heads is “consecutive” if it is preceded or followed by heads, or that it is “consecutive” if it is preceded by heads. In the former case, `HHTHH` would be an instance of $4$ consecutive heads, and in the latter case `HHHHH`would be an instance, whereas `HHHH` wouldn’t. This is clearly not how the phrase “$4$ consecutive heads” is conventionally used.

So if “consecutive” isn’t a property of individual heads, perhaps we can interpret it to refer to pairs of consecutive heads. But that doesn’t work either, since “$4$ pairs of consecutive heads” would include `HHTHHTHHTHH`, which is clearly also not how “$4$ consecutive heads” is conventionally used.

Rather “4 consecutive heads” is conventionally used to mean “a run of $4$ consecutive heads”. This is also how you seem to be interpreting it, as you have a run of $4$ consecutive heads in your example `HHHHTHH`. (Incidentally, that example also has exactly $4$ pairs of consecutive heads.)

But if “$4$ consecutive heads” is short for “a run of $4$ consecutive heads”, then “only/exactly $4$ consecutive heads” should be short for “a run of only/exactly $4$ consecutive heads”. That would speak in favour of interpreting “only/exactly” as limiting the number of consecutive heads in a run. Then “there are only/exactly $4$ consecutive heads“ could be taken to mean “there is a run of only/exactly $4$ consecutive heads”. If so, `HHHHTHH` would qualify.

All this is, of course, merely a speculative attempt at clarifying what is unclear. As has been stated in the comments, if possible it would be best to ask the author to clarify.

Comment: Isn't the latter part in the case of {HHHHTHH} -> {HH} two consecutive heads? Then, two consecutive heads will not even satisfy "4 consecutive heads". This can satisfy only if the word 'only/ exactly' means the limit to the maximum number of consecutive heads as I interpreted in your answer, instead of just the number of consecutive heads in the tosses. Am I wrong? Thanks for replying to me!

Comment: @DiamondMaths: I'm sorry, I'm having difficulty relating what you wrote to what I wrote. Could you be more specific? What are you referring to by "the limit to the maximum number of consecutive heads as I interpreted in your answer"?

Comment: To put it simply, there are 2 consecutive 'H' after 'T' in {HHHHTHH}. However, 2 consecutive 'H' is not 4 consecutive 'H'. In this regard, isn't the case {HHHHTHH} not be possible for the question that requires 'exactly' 4 consecutive 'H' (no more or less than 4 consecutive 'H' within 7 tosses)? Is there any logic or linguistic mistake in my understanding?

Comment: I mean no other consecutive 'H' that has more or less than 4 consecutive tosses within 7 tosses in total.

Comment: @DiamondMaths: Again, the problem statement is unclear and we can only speculate. However, to me it's not plausible that the intended meaning is "there is exactly one run of $4$ consecutive heads and no other pairs of consecutive heads". I don't see how to express this idea without referring to both runs and pairs (or individual heads), and it seems implausible to me that the one formulation "$4$ consecutive heads" should be intended to refer both to runs and to pairs. I tried to spell this out in my answer. It's just my best guess; only the author really knows.